# How to apply display none for child div's by accessing them from parent div using css selectors

Tags: css

I am working with Css for me code is getting dynamically so can someone please explain how to apply display none for child div's by accessing parent div using css selectors. for me code is getting dynamically so I am Image of code [image]

So from my code how to apply display none for this div --->

```
<div class="jsx-674079454 topbar"></div>
```

So my question with Image for better understanding.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Please post always all code instead of image, you need to access this `<div class="jsx-674079454 topbar"></div>` from this `<div id="__next">` ?

Comment: need more exactly direction: which element do you mean? Write accurate selector, please

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first method is the simplest use directly the class like:

```css
.topbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='_next'>
  <div class='randomoijosj'>
    <div class='randomoijokpokpokosj call'>
      <div class='randomoijosjytfty topbar'>hideme</div>
      <div class='randomoijosjtyf main'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `>` selector like:

```css
#_next>div>div>div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='_next'>
  <div class='randomoijosj'>
    <div class='randomoijokpokpokosj call'>
      <div class='randomoijosjytfty topbar'>hideme</div>
      <div class='randomoijosjtyf main'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Simone Rossaini I tried your code but it's not working for me.

Comment: i copy the structure you posted and as you can see all work.

Comment: Have you try both solution?